# How to add a column to a table on production PostgreSQL with zero downtime?

Tags: postgresql, production-environment, alter-table, downtime

Here 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53016193/10894456
is an answer provided for Oracle 11g,
My question is the same:

> What is the best approach to add a not null column with default value
>   in production oracle database when that table contain one million
>   records and it is live. Does it create any locks if we do the column
>   creation , adding default value and making it as not null in a single
>   statement?

but for PostgreSQL ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This prior answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19525083/does-adding-a-null-column-to-a-postgres-table-cause-a-lock) essentially answers your query.

Cross referencing the [relevant PostgreSQL doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html) with the PostgreSQL sourcecode for [`AlterTableGetLockLevel`](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/backend/commands/tablecmds.c#L3639) mentioned in the above answer shows that `ALTER TABLE ... ADD COLUMN` will always obtain an `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` table lock, precluding any other transaction from accessing the table for the duration of the `ADD COLUMN` operation.
This same exclusive lock is obtained for any `ADD COLUMN` variation; ie. it doesn't matter whether you add a `NULL` column (with or without `DEFAULT`) or have a `NOT NULL` with a default.

However, as mentioned in the linked answer above, adding a `NULL` column with no `DEFAULT` should be very quick as this operation simply updates the catalog.

In contrast, adding a column with a `DEFAULT` specifier necessitates a rewrite the entire table in PostgreSQL 10 or less.
This operation is likely to take a considerable time on your 1M record table.
According to the linked answer, PostgreSQL >= 11 does not require such a rewrite for adding such a column, so should perform more similarly to the no-`DEFAULT` case.

I should add that for PostgreSQL 11 and above, the [`ALTER TABLE` docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html#AEN57290) note that table rewrites are only avoided for non-volatile `DEFAULT` specifiers:

> When a column is added with ADD COLUMN and a non-volatile DEFAULT is specified, the default is evaluated at the time of the statement and the result stored in the table's metadata. That value will be used for the column for all existing rows. If no DEFAULT is specified, NULL is used. In neither case is a rewrite of the table required.
>
> Adding a column with a volatile DEFAULT [...] will require the entire table and its indexes to be rewritten. [...] Table and/or index rebuilds may take a significant amount of time for a large table; and will temporarily require as much as double the disk space.

Comment: Precisely. From v11 on this is blazingly fast. It still needs a short `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock, because the table definition changes. If that is disruptive or not depends on the concurrent activity: long running transactions will cause trouble (as always).